# Question about $\text{non}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, infinitary-combinatorics

A lemma in Kunen's (2011) set theory states that if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal with $\kappa=\text{cf}(\gamma)>\omega$, then $\text{add}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)$ $=$ $\text{cov}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)$ $=$ $\text{non}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)$ $=$ $\kappa$.

(Where $X\notin\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma\iff X\text{ is stationary}$ in $\gamma$)

He says that this lemma follows easily from the definitions along with the three facts:

1. The intersection of any family of fewer than $\kappa$ club subsets of $\gamma$ is club.
2. There is a family of $\kappa$ club subsets of $\gamma$ whose intersection is empty.
3. If $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal on $A$ with $[A]^{<\omega}\subseteq\mathcal{I}$, then $\text{add}(\mathcal{I})\le\text{non}(\mathcal{I})\le|A|$, $\text{add}(\mathcal{I})\le\text{cov}(\mathcal{I})\le|A|$, and $\text{add}(\mathcal{I})$ is regular.

From these, I am able to see that $\text{add}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)=\text{cov}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)=\kappa$. I was also able to deduce that any stationary $X\subseteq\gamma$ will have $\text{sup}(X)=\gamma$, which implies that $\text{non}(\mathsf{nonstat}_\gamma)\ge\kappa$.

But I can't think of a stationary $X\subseteq\gamma$ with cardinality $\kappa$. (When $\gamma$ is regular, I could simply take $X=\gamma$, but that won't work when $\gamma$ is singular).

So my question is: What stationary subset of $\gamma$ has cardinality $\kappa$ (when $\gamma$ is singular)?

Any help is appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is singular of cofinality $\kappa$, then there is a normal function $f\colon\kappa\to\gamma$ such that $\sup\operatorname{rng}(f)=\gamma$.

You can check and see that $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is indeed a club in $\gamma$, and its cardinality is indeed $\kappa$. Now since clubs are stationary sets...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize all clubs are stationary until you said it, but now I see it follows easily from fact 1. Also, I see that an increasing $\kappa$-sequence of ordinals cofinal in $\gamma$ won't guarantee that the sequence is closed in $\gamma$, but the normal function you presented is how we can get a club subset of $\gamma$ of size $\kappa$. Would you happen to know if there is a stationary subset of $\gamma$ of size $\kappa$ which is not club?

Comment: @user52534: Sure, take this club of size $\kappa$, and look at the ordinals with countable cofinality there.

Comment: ...unless $\kappa = \omega_1$ (regarding your comment.)

Comment: @Trevor: True. But the general idea is transferable to this case as well. Just pick any stationary co-stationary subset of $\kappa$ and use the normal function to turn it into a stationary subset of $\gamma$.